# cxf-codegen-plugin could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251/../lib/tools.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven, cxf-codegen-plugin

I am using a springboot application and generating stub using cxf codegen plugin.
I have JDK_HOME configured to run my springboot project.

After upgrading the cxf-version from 3.2.4 to 3.3.6, I see the below error in my pom.xml.

```
Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.3.6:wsdl2java failed: Plugin org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.3.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251/../lib/tools.jar (org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.3.6:wsdl2java:generate-sources:generate-sources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.3.6:wsdl2java failed: Plugin org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.3.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251/../lib/tools.jar
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$7(MavenImpl.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.3.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251/../lib/tools.jar
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:218)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.EclipsePluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(EclipsePluginDependenciesResolver.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:402)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:105)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251/../lib/tools.jar
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:338)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:210)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251/../lib/tools.jar
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:264)
    ... 39 more
```

When I tried reducing the cxf version all the way till 3.3.2, this issue doesn't appear.
Also, this error is not a build-breaker, but unable to get out of my head whenever I see that my pom.xml is seen with red marker.

Any help would be appreciated

my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${cxf.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>generate-sources</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf
            </sourceRoot>
            <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/wsdl/test.wsdl
                    </wsdl>
                    <frontEnd>jaxws21</frontEnd>
                    <faultSerialVersionUID>1</faultSerialVersionUID>
                    <extraargs>
                        <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                    </extraargs>
                </wsdlOption>
            </wsdlOptions>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JDK to compile instead of jre.

Comment: Hello @Rome, external link aren't allowed due to volatilty of external links. Please remove the link and provide a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes maven plugins use the JAVA_HOME environment variable to use jdk's tools.

From my understanding your system define a JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to a JRE.

Possible solutions:

- Delete the JAVA_HOME environment variable or update the value to a compliant JDK
- Use maven toolchain configuration if "cxf-codegen-plugin" allows it